# How to duplicate/ reproduce records in T SQL by combining between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have 2 tables.

- Table no. 1 has a gender (ladies, men), organization code and some additional attributes.
- Table no. 2 has gender, gender attributes and organization code.

I need to combine between these table and to present this final result. How should I join between them in order to have each record in the table no. 2 duplicated according to the table no. 1?

```
**Tbl no 1:**
 ORGCODE  /  GENDER  /  CUSTOMER  /  COUNTRY
 SUB      /  MEN     /  ABC       /  EFD
 SUB      /  MEN     /  ACD       /  GFH
 JUB      /  LADIES  /  HFR       /  KLU
 SUB      /  LADIES  /  YUJ       /  DER
 JUB      /  LADIES  /  JYR       /  DRT
 JUB      /  LADIES  /  PIO       /  GFT

**Tbl no 2:**
ORGCODE  /  GENDER  /  GENDERDESC
SUB      /  LADIES  /  PL
SUB      /  LADIES  /  REG
SUB      /  MEN     /  REG
JUB      /  LADIES  /  REG
JUB      /  LADIES  /  PET
JUB      /  LADIES  /  PL

**Tbl no 3- the desired final view:**
ORGCODE  /  GENDER  /  GENDERDESC
SUB      /  MEN     /  PL
SUB      /  MEN     /  REG
JUB      /  LADIES  /  REG
SUB      /  LADIES  /  REG
JUB      /  LADIES  /  PET
JUB      /  LADIES  /  PL
```

I don't see any option to attach a file or to paste the picture/ excel table (very short)

Comment: Read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see any logic in the result. Why is MEN/PET not included? Why is MEN/PL included? What relevance does the first table have?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   t1.ORGCODE,
   t1.GENDER,
   t2.GENDERDESC,
FROM [tbl no 1] AS t1 
INNER JOIN [tbl no 2] AS t2 
    ON t1.ORGCODE = t2.ORGCODE
```

I don't know if i understood what you want, but this is what i think you ask for.

Comment: Your query doesn't match the OP's table structure or desired results. You should either significantly revise the answer or delete it.